# Manage changes to cassandra.yaml and cassandra-env.sh

Tags: cassandra, datastax

How do you manage changes made to cassandra.yaml and cassandra-env.sh? During upgrading cassandra to a newer version, if you choose to retain the modified file, you will lose any new changes to those files.

Comment: I keep them in git, and push them out with a deploy.

Answer (score 1):

you should merge your original changes back into the new files. This is because there may be new parameters introduced into the new file with new features or indeed new default values for new or existing features. Using an old file might cause you problems.

Use a good merge tool like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) (linux) or [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) (windows) to merge your files. Once you have a good template you can use this as a template.